# laravel include js script based on language

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, include

I'm working on a Laravel 5.4 project and I need to include specific js script (or any other resource type like image and css) based on user selected language. Currently I use follow syntax:

```
{!! HTML::script('js/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js') !!}
```

than correctly include the main js file that is valid for all languages.

The validate plugin show error messages based on user browser language but I want that the language change when the user choose a different language.

So i try:

```
{!! HTML::script('js/jquery-validation/localization/messages_'){{ Config::get('app.locale') }} !!}
```

and

```
{!! HTML::script('js/jquery-validation/localization/messages_') !!}{{ Config::get('app.locale') }}
```

But both don't work.

The first one throw an exception, the second one produce wrong code

```
<script src="http://dev-site.me/js/jquery-validation/localization/messages_"></script>
de.js
```

(obliviously.. because the "locale" part is outside the include declaration.. but I just try.. :P )

so I need a way to create an html like:

```
<script src="http://yearly-review.me/js/jquery-validation/localization/messages_de.js"></script>
```

where de.js is a dynamic part based on a variable how can I do this?

Comment: Try @php $url = 'js/jquery-validation/localization/messages_'.Config::get('app.locale')@endphp {{{!! HTML::script($url)!!}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it once:

```
{!! Html::script('js/jquery-validation/localization/messages_' . config('app.locale')) !!}
```

Comment: Perfect!! thank you! a so simple solution :P just to be more correct.. the final right solution is {!! Html::script('js/jquery-validation/localization/messages_' . config('app.locale').".js") !!} otherwise you miss the extension

Comment: I am so sorry. It is my mistake.